# Select and save as shapefile feature in R using sf

Tags: raster, shapefile, r, select-by-attribute, sf

How can I select the shapefile feature there is, "D3" in "New.Code" columns using sf packages in R

[image]

Here is the attribute table of my shapefile:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Select rows like its a data frame, and use `st_write` to make a shapefile:

```
st_write(thing[thing$New.Code=="D3",], "justD3.shp")
```

If you are struggling with this, you should probably read a good introduction to R and spatial data in R, to get familiar with the basics.

Comment: Thankyou so much for the answer